# How do i convert a string of ascii values to there original character/number in python

Tags: python, string, numbers, ascii

i have a string with numbers that i previously converted with my encoder but now i am trying to decode it ive searched around and no answers seem to work
if you have any i dear how to do this then let me know

string = 91 39 65 97 66 98 67 99 32 49 50 51 39 93

outcome = ABCabc 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outcome = "".join([your_decoder.decode(x) for x in string.split(" ")])
```

Comment: give a code of your decoder? If your decoder is simple transformation from ascii to number, use 

outcome = "".join([chr(int(x)) for x in string.split(" ")])